# Unproven inequality in textbook

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-distribution

I was reading through the solution to a problem in a probability textbook and the author applied the following inequality without proving it: $$(1-\mathbb{P}(\text{Bin}(k,1/2)>s))^{t-1} \leq 2^{-|\Omega|(t\mathbb{P}(\text{Bin}(k,1/2)>s))}.$$

$\text{Bin}$ is the binomial distribution, and $s,t,k$ are natural numbers s.t. $t,k>0$, $0 < s < k$.

So the inequality above is equivalent to proving the following inequality,
$$(t-1)\log_2(1-\mathbb{P}(\text{Bin}(k,1/2)>s))\geq -|\Omega|(t\mathbb{P}(\text{Bin}(k,1/2)>s)).$$
I am not really sure how to proceed here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\Omega$? The sample space? Or the cardinality of the sample space?